# Making a Darlington transistor (eg: TIP120) with D882 to drive 12V LEDs with 3.3V or 5V input RPi

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, raspberry-pi, surface-mount, darlington

I am getting into circuits and trying to improve my knowledge but even though it might sound like a silly question but here is my story short:

#### What I am trying to do

I am building a circuit to drive an LED strip (12v) out of a Raspberry Pi using PWM output.

It worked out perfectly using a TIP120 on the breadboard using the following example:

[image]

#### My goals

Now that it is working, I am building a PCB to send to JLCPB to have it printed and assembled so I wish to use basic parts as much as possible and ended up selecting a D882 transistor which is not a Darlington.  I heard that it might cause issues to my actual circuit and not expecting the same result as with the TIP120.

So a using D882 transistor I kind of recreated the schematic of the TIP120.

Am I silly to say that this will do the same thing as the TIP120?

[image]

Am I in the wrong way and another SMD component would do the trick?

### Update

Channel 1 at 100%, seem to get alot of noise but Channel 2 at 50% is quite stable.

[image]

Here you can see the quick simple prototype

[image]

Comment: Unfamiliar with RPi: are those outputs current limited? If not you definately need to add a base resistor.

Comment: Yes, they are limited to 5v.

Comment: Both schematics are insufficient due to lack of base current limiting R missing and voltage rise when saturated on output.  It is better to use open drain power FETs for interfacing 12V LEDstrips . or two stage inverting BJTs PNP+NPN with proper R values to reduce Vce(sat) <0.4V vs 1.7V @ 3A on your choices, you must specify load current and output  max current you choose from Rpi.

Comment: @maxleb Current is not expressed in Volts...

Comment: @maxleb You've already said that the TIP120 works well for your needs. This tells us that you don't need all of the +12 V supply potential because the TIP120 drops about 1.5 V of it. You are now in a position where you don't want to specify the TIP120 but want, instead, to design a replacement that meets additional requirements. At this point, I think we need to know more about the worst case current compliance needed and I think you need to re-evaluate the voltage drop (because in a new design you get to do that.) And what PWM rate are you using and what's the dynamic range of the duty cycle?

Comment: @maxleb:  [Raspberry Pi GPIO pins have a nominal 3.3V output.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/gpio/README.md)  They are also not intended to pass more than about 16 milliamperes.  Connecting the base of a large transistor to a GPIO without a resistor to limit the current could damage the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @jonk, duty cycle will go between 0-100% depending on the color I will need (RGB) So currently at 100% duty cycle I get 1.5v - 35mA in the input and 11.13v - 238mA on the output so I get a 0.7v drop. Cutting in half at 50% duty cycle. So in my case, the voltage drop is not an issue as the led light up bright enough.

Comment: @JRE, so is this why I get a noisy cycle on channel one cause it's requiring to much current?

Comment: I don't know how or where you measured what with channel 1 and channel 2.

Comment: Your connection in the picture is not the same, and there was something about the i2c pins that even though they are configurable to GPIO, they don't have the same current drive as the dedicated GPIO.

Comment: Your noise is mostly measurement error with 1:1 probes and noisy ground loops.

Comment: Your  1.5V to 1.6V Vbe clamp on Ch2 for your Rpi LVCMOS driver implies your Darlington gets enough base current but you are well exceeding the recommended 20mA or 25mA absolute max. (16mA just for Logic loads with noise immunity) possibly 50 mA. Not good for reliability as it may fuse open in time.  Ch1 looks like 2.5 div. X 500mV/div = 1.25V same boat or worse... N.G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a surface mount version of a tip120, the MJD122 would work, but I would recommend the fallowing to protect your GPIO from the 12V, which is 3.3V i/o on a raspberry pi.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqgtnf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
But either way, the efficiency of using a transistor with this micro controller board is not going to be that good to begin with. Now, if we use an enhancement mode MOSFET instead of a darlington, then the low voltage cmos from the raspberry pi (2.5V logic hi) would drive the circuit efficiently, and more like a switch. So I would recommend for raspberry pi, this kind of driver circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPw2JC.png)</sup>

Comment: Vce(sat)=2Vmax @ 4A for Ib=16mA yet for Vout=3.3V and Vb= ~1.2V to 1.5V your Rb=2k only provides 1.8V/2k <1mA to 1.1V/2k= 0.55mA so with a saturated hFE of only 250 , it can drive about 130mA  , your  Vce(sat) might rise to 3V with more current reducing LED brightness.  Not a great solution but will turn on lights

Comment: That is why enhance mode mosfets would be a better choice in this application @TonyStewartEE75 instead of a darlington transistor. Because the Raspberry pi are low voltage cmos outputs.  Even reducing the safety resistor to its minimum at 1K is still not really enough drive. 2.5V logic hi. But I guess the OP is wanting to use a transistor driver. On other micro controllers that are TTL level, this is not an issue

Comment: Yes I suggested FETs in comments to avoid the problems not clarified in your answer. For  this application.

Comment: I added a MOSFET circuit just in case the OP wants a better solution for his app.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMikeska, as I don't have those parts in stock I will test it out as you mentionned as soon as I get the missing parts. Good enough for an accepted answer.